# Delegate static methods with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I use delegate to delegate a static method?

I am trying to do the following

e.g.

```
class MyThing
  def some_instance_method(a, b)
    something.some_instance_method(a, b)
  end

  def some_static_method(a, b)
    User.some_static_method(a, b)
  end
end

# can you write it this way???

class MyThing
  delegate :some_instance_method, :to => :something
  delegate :some_static_method, :to => User
end
```

Comment: Death. To. Static. Methods. Anyway, it ought to work if doing `class << MyThing; delegate ..; end`, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class MyThing
  class << self
    delegate :some_static_method, :to => :User
  end
end
```